# Insert a number between every element in my array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am completely stuck when it comes to the C language and inserting into arrays. I have my code below and to explain it say the user wants an array of 3. So the user inputs 4 3 2 into array `a1[n]`. I need array `a2[]` to output the same numbers but a zero between each. The end result would be 4 0 3 0 2 0 when `a2[]` is output. How would I get a zero between every other element?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

    int n = 0; 
    int number = 0; 
    int a1[n]; 
    int a2[2 * n];

    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");  
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ //adds values to first array
            scanf("%d",&number);
            a1[i] = number; } 

   for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ //copies and sets the arrays the same
            a2[i] = a1[i]; }
```

Comment: Is it necessarily to have an array with those zeros? You can simply insert them while outputting array.

Comment: No it is not necessary but would help me to learn either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your arrays are correctly defined and initialized (statically or dynamically), it is just a matter of properly counting during copying:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        a2[i+i] = a1[i]; 
        if(i < n-1) a2[i+i+1] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much this was the for loop I needed! A little more complex then I would of thought of myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 0; 
int number = 0; 
int a1[n]; 
int a2[2 * n];
```

Congratulations, now `a1` and `a2` are arrays of zero length.  Even if you change `n` later, this doesn't affect the lengths of arrays.  In C, you cannot make an array longer or shorter.

Try `int*` and `calloc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't create `stack-allocated` or `static` array with runtime-defined size.

```
int a[N]; // N should be determined during compilation
```

You should use `heap-alloceted` or `dynamic` array:

```
int *a;
a = (int *)malloc(2 * n, sizeof(int)); // n may be defined by user input
```

There is no way to resize array without moving it to another place, and you can just create a new one (larger then first) and fill it with source numbers and zeroes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0; 
    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");  
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *a1 = (int *)malloc(n, sizeof(int));
    int *a2 = (int *)malloc(n * 2, sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

    int i, number;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ //adds values to first array
        scanf("%d",&number);
        a1[i] = number;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ //copies and sets the arrays the same
        a2[i * 2] = a1[i];
        a2[i * 2 + 1] = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n * 2; ++i){
        printf("%d ", a2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) do allow you to create stack-allocated arrays with runtime-defined size.

Comment: "you can't create stack-allocated ... with runtime-defined size" --> Are you saying code can not use `scanf("%d", &n); int a1[n];`?  (VLA in C99)

Comment: Those `malloc` should be freed.

Comment: @chux exactly I am

Comment: @3kt does it matter?

Comment: @user3386109 I dont quite understand you, but I want to say that only way to create array with `input-defined` size is to use `malloc` (or calloc, or other functions)

Comment: C99 allows [Variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) as commented by @user3386109 which contradicts the first sentence.

Comment: @LibertyPaul it's a good habit to have in my opinion. It's not _required_ in this case though, but the matter has already been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339134/does-every-malloc-call-have-to-be-freed)

Comment: @chux I didn't knew anything about it, but VLA is now deprecated so you shouldn't use it anyway

Comment: @LibertyPaul variable length arrays are optional in C11.  Please provide citation for " VLA is now deprecated".

Comment: @chux `although subsequently relegated in C11 to a conditional feature which implementations are not required to support`

Comment: Your citation, (not part of the C spec) does not imply depreciation.  The C11 has dozens of attributes that are _not required to support_.  This is not the same as _depreciated_.  Further the issue is what is possible, not necessary prudent, hence my initial comment concerning "can't create stack-allocated or static array" when C99 and select C11 code can do.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in last loop.

for ( j=0, i=0; i <= n; i++ ) {

```
a2[j++] = a1[i];
a2[j++] = 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You have to multiply the indices by 2:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) { //copies and sets the arrays the same
    a2[2 * i] = a1[i];
}
```

Not only that, odd-indexed elements of `a2` should be set to zero. You can do it explicitly in loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) a2[2 * i + 1] = 0;
```

But simpler is to first initialize the array with zeroes:

```
int a2[2 * n] = {0};
```

Even-numbered elements will later be overwritten with elements of `a1`.